# Creating a empty table using SchemaRDD in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to create a empty table using SchemaRDD -sqlcontext in Scala?I need it to be
empty during the first load to the table and during subsequent loads
the table will have records in it.

In the Below Query table1 is empty during the first load.

```
select a.c_id,a.m_cd,a.linkid from table1 a leftouterjoin basetab b on
a .c_id=b.c_id and a.m_cd=b.m_cd where b.cid is null ;
```

Please Help!!

Thanks,
Priya

Comment: If `table1` is empty output after left outer join will be empty as well.

Comment: yes that is true.But how would i  be able to refer this table in query without having any data in it .Basically i  want to know  how to create a table  in schemaRDD with no records in it.

Comment: This is why it is marked as a duplicate.